DynamoDB scan with umlaut in ExpressionAttributeValues is returning no results
I run some scan request on a dynamoDB table to find User based on their first and/or last names, which can contain umlaut characters like öäü. My JSON request looks like
 {"TableName":"user-table-name","FilterExpression":"contains(#firstName, :firstName) and contains(#lastName, :lastName)","ExpressionAttributeNames":{"#firstName":"firstName","#lastName":"lastName"},"ExpressionAttributeValues":{":firstName":"ÖÄÜ",":lastName":"öäü"}}

But I am getting no results for this query, although the entry exists in the table and I am able to scan/query it on the AWS Console. Anyone know why this happens? Does DynamoDB not support characters like umlaut?
Any tips would be greatly appreciated...

Needs to be UTF-8 encoding, I think. Did you try a template literal such as \ÖÄÜ``?

Mhh so I tried encode my string in this request with Buffer.from(params.lastName, 'utf-8').toString().  Which results into the same JSON request parameters. Or do you mean the complete JSON should be utf-8 before sending it out?

Just got you point with the literal and yes this works. When I request a litteral I get a found user. So this means that whatever I get from my string vars i need to make into whatever the literal form is... Any idea how to make this in typescript?

So this works:
          ":firstName": `ÄÖÜ`,
          ":lastName": `äöü`,

but this does not
         ":firstName": `${Buffer.from(`ÄÖÜ`, 'utf-8').toString()}`,
          ":lastName": `${Buffer.from(`äöü`, 'utf-8').toString()}`,

